# Table layout fixed only for one column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to specify a percentage width for one column and let the rest be calculated as normal. I need one column to allow anything too long to scroll in the table cell.

If I set `table-layout: fixed`, the percentage width column is sized correctly and the scrolling happens as expected, but the rest of the columns are evenly spaced and look awful.

If I set `table-layout: auto`, the percentage width is ignored and the column in question grows to accommodate the content instead of cutting it off with a scrollbar.

Is there a way to force a percentage width on one column while allowing the others to be sized to their content?

edit--here's a pen that shows that the column width is only honored with `table-layout: fixed`:
https://codepen.io/jugglervr/pen/vYxNYEa

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand your question correctly but simply putting a fixed width on the column you want will force it to fit to its size.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 100px">Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100px">Sample Name</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Web Developer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100px">Another Name</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>Jobless</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I updated my ask with a codepen that shows how your solution fails. Note what happens to the name column when you disable `table-layout: fixed`. The overlap behavior is what's desired so I can enforce the width and make the cell scrollable.

Comment: Do you want a table-layout: fixed with 1 column that has fixed width?

Comment: Also you might want to put overflow-x: auto on the name class on your codepen

Comment: "Do you want a table-layout: fixed with 1 column that has fixed width?" yep. I want normal table column distribution everywhere except a single column, that I specify to always be a certain width. It's unreal to me that specifying a width doesn't result in that width being honored. lol

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your question. In the other answer, you wrote, you wanted it to overflow, but that is what it is doing. If possible, could you add a picture of what you actually want it to do? (Can't comment, as I am new to Stack Overflow)

Comment: I want it to overflow, and then size the rest of the columns according to their content. When I set `table-layout: auto` it ignores my width and sets all of the columns according to their content. When I set it to `fixed`, it honors my width and then sizes the rest of the columns *the same width*, NOT appropriate to their content.